# How to force state hover in element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a sidenav that when applied hover with the mouse it expands but needed to force the hover without the mouse necessarily being over the element

What I need is that when the page starts it automatically starts with the hover applied and after a few seconds unapply

.html

```
<div class="sidenav custom-sidenav" #sideNav>
  <div class="text-sidenav">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

.css

```
   .custom-sidenav div {
      position: fixed;
      right: -120px; 
      transition: 0.3s; 
      padding: 15px; 
      width: 140px; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      font-size: 20px; 
      color: white; 
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; 
      z-index: 100;
    }

    .custom-sidenav div:hover {
      right: 0; 
    }

    .text-sidenav {
      position: relative;
      top: 200px;
      background-color: #2196F3; /* Blue */
    }
```

i try use ViewChild with elementRef but show this error

> this.sideNav.nativeElement.mouseover is not a function

my ts

```
  @ViewChild('sideNav') private sideNav: ElementRef;

  @Input() text: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sideNav.nativeElement.mouseover();
  }
```

Comment: I'd suggest that your plan is flawed. Instead of relying on a pseudo-hover state, just set the behavior you want directly. Use a CSS class.

Comment: @isherwood is right. Websites can not control users' mouse (and that is a good thing!)

Comment: Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: @isherwood I managed to solve by applying a class with [class] thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of @isherwood

> I'd suggest that your plan is flawed. Instead of relying on a
>   pseudo-hover state, just set the behavior you want directly. Use a CSS
>   class

html

```
<div class="sidenav custom-sidenav" [class.custom-sidenav-hover]="show">
  <div class="text-sidenav">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.custom-sidenav div {
  position: fixed;
  right: -120px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 140px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.custom-sidenav-hover div{
  right: 0;
}


.text-sidenav {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

my ts

```
  @Input() text: string;
  @Input() cont: number;

  show: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.show = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.show = false;
    }, this.cont);
  }
```